# cv2 grayscale has 3 channels and a weird blueish-yellowish tint

Tags: python, image, opencv, grayscale

I have the following issue with cv2
when i normally load the image, everything is fine:

```
    img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(img)
    print(img.shape)
```

[image]

When i try to load grayscale though, i get the following issue

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(gray)
print(gray.shape)
```

This gives me 4 channels, but at least a gray image

[image]

But this code

```
plt.show()
img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

gives me 1 channel but a weird blueish yellowish image

[image]

My question is,
can i load a gray image that has 1 channel?
Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenCV reads the image correctly, the issue lies in MatPlotLib's `imshow()` function because it displays single-channel images as colormaps.

To specify grayscale, pass a `cmap` parameter to the imshow function like so:

```py
img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(img.shape)
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

Note: In your examples you used `cv2.imread(file, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` and `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` respectively.
`cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB` and `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` are both flags that tell the `imread()` and `cvtColor()` functions how to behave (e.g. return a grayscale image). While they are both accepted by the functions, they may not do what you want them to, and for this reason it is recommended to only use the flags specified for each function. Any flag beginning with `IMREAD_` should only be used with OpenCV's `imread()` function. Likewise, any flag beginning with `COLOR_` should only be used with `cvtColor()`

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about the note? I am not sure I understand. Otherwise thanks! Would it be correct to assume that it is an imshow issue and not a cv2 issue? I.e. the values in the matrix are grayscale.? (They are for a CNN)

Comment: @john No worries! I elaborated more on the note, and included the fact that this is not an OpenCV issue, but simply the representation matplotlib uses. The values in the `image` object are the same, so as long as you use that for your processing you won't have a problem. If my answer was what you were looking for you can select it as the accepted answer :)